# Finding common Files from two arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to find common name files from two arrays.
I have saved file names of two different folders in two different arrays.

Now i am creating a common file array which will have files which have common name.

filenames 1 : Array contaning names of file in folder 1.

filename 2 : Array contaning names of file in folder 2.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;

public class ListFiles1 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        String path1 = "C:\\"; 

        String path2 = "D:\\"; 

        File folder1 = new File(path1);
        File folder2 = new File(path2);

        String[] f1=folder1.list();

        File[] listOfFiles1 = folder1.listFiles(); 
        File[] listOfFiles2 = folder2.listFiles(); 

        ArrayList<String> fileNames1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> fileNames2 = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles1.length; i++) 
        {

            if (listOfFiles1[i].isFile()) 
            {
                fileNames1.add(listOfFiles1[i].getName());
                System.out.println(f1[i] + " is a file");
            }

        }

        for (int j = 0; j < listOfFiles2.length; j++) 
        {

            if (listOfFiles2[j].isFile()) 
            {
                fileNames2.add(listOfFiles2[j].getName());
            }
        }

        ArrayList<String> commonfiles = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles1.length; i++)
        {
        for (int j = 0; i < listOfFiles2.length; j++) 
            {
            String tempfilename1;
            String tempfilename2;
            tempfilename1=fileNames1[i];
            tempfilename2 = fileNames2[j];
            if(tempfilename1.equals(tempfilename2))
                {
                commonfiles.add(tempfilename1);
                }
            }
        }                   
    }
}
```

I wrote this code but the compiler gives this error:

```
   Main.java:52: error: array required, but ArrayList<String> found
            tempfilename1=fileNames1[i];
                                    ^
Main.java:53: error: array required, but ArrayList<String> found
            tempfilename2 = fileNames2[j];
                                      ^
```

> P.S : I am a Newbie...

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: Check your variables. I think you made the input as arrays of strings and trying to using it as an arraylist.

Comment: Not relevant but I couldnt resist myself: an advice, get the  

String tempfilename1;
tempfilename1=filenames1.get(i);

part out of the inner loop, save some cpu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `filenames1` is an `array` you cannot use `ArrayList` method `get(int i)`.

You need to access the `array` elements by using `arrayName[elementIndex]`.

In your case:

```
tempfilename1=filenames1[i];
tempfilename2=fileNames2[j];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following to get the common set of strings between both arrays:

```
    String[] listOfFiles1 = {"file1", "file2", "file3"};
    String[] listOfFiles2 = {"file2", "file3", "file5"};

    HashSet<String> common = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(listOfFiles1));
    common.retainAll(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(listOfFiles2)));

    System.out.println(common); // -> output: file2, file3
```

You don't need to convert them to Sets though, but this would remove the risk of duplicate keys. If you do want to show duplicates you could simplify it a bit:

```
    List<String> common = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(listOfFiles1));
    list1.retainAll(Arrays.asList(listOfFiles2));
```